# Binary Tree in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement a binary tree in C++ and transverse it in a root-left-right manner. After I add all the nodes I get a crash at this line:

```
cout << r->st->st->info << endl; //trying to print root->left->left->info
```

My RSD function doesn't print anything. Also, I would appreciate any Visual Studio tutorials on how to use the debugger. Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Nod{
    int info;
    Nod *st, *dr;
};

int read_tree(Nod *r)
{
    int info;
    cout << "Info: "; cin >> info;
    if (info!=0)
    {
        r = new Nod;
        r->info = info;
        read_tree(r->st);
        read_tree(r->dr);
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

void RSD(Nod *r)
{
    if (r != NULL)
    {
        cout << r->info << " ";
        RSD(r->st);
        RSD(r->dr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Nod *r = NULL;
    read_tree(r);
    system("Pause");
    cout << r->st->st->info << endl;
    cout << r->dr->info;
    RSD(r);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `r` right after calling read_tree(). Is it NULL?

Comment: After the `read_tree()` call is completed, how do you know that there are at least 2 `st` (left child) and at least 1 `dr` (right child) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you pass a copy of a pointer to a `read_tree` function. That is, when you call `read_tree(r)` in the main function, `r` remains `NULL` regardless of what happens inside the `read_tree` function. You can fix it by passing a pointer by reference. That is, changing `read_tree(Nod* r)` to `read_tree(Nod*& r)` should fix it.

Comment: I understand now. One more problem now is that I'm getting a crush in my RSD function at `cout << r->info << " ";`. What does cause this?  Thank you,

Comment: @Shury  When you allocate a `new Nod`, the `st` and `dr` pointers are uninitialized. They are not guaranteed to be `NULL`. You can initialize them in a `Nod` constructor.